# .sh can only be executed by explicitly typing bash

Tags: linux, bash

When I run sudo ./hello.sh form command line, it says:
: command not found
but when I explicitly type bash like :sudo bash ./hello.sh
it run successful,why?

Comment: And what is inside your script? Did it start with maybe wrong #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: Or you simply haven't set the file's executable bit.

Comment: `why?` you have to show the file, we can't quess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first line of your Bash Script you should use `shebang`.
for your script `shebang` is like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

After that your script should be executable. use this command:

```
chomd +x hello.sh
```

now run your script.

```
 sudo ./hello.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is indeed due to some reason that the file does not have executable permissions